# ADT - Changing an application code and seeing the results instantly

Tags: android, debugging

I'm currently developing an application for Android, using ADT and a tablet plugged in my computer in USB debug mode. Whenever I change my code I have to "commit", that is re-running the app, so I can see the changes I made. Can be a bit of a bummer. Is there a way to not have to do this? Something like "code-pushing" or similar. After all, this is in debug mode.
Reason I ask this is because I recall watching that documentary about Minecraft, and seeing Notch using debug mode in eclipse and making changes to the game instantly *without ever closing or reloading the game*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Android Java, you could use the [layout designer](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/designing-layout-of-android-application.html), thought it's probably not what you're looking for (I thought I'd have to mention it). If you're looking for an instant preview, you have to be willing to change your current development environment and language.

- Currently, [Unity](http://unity3d.com/) and/or [Chaos Project](http://www.chaos-project.com/) can give you pretty good previews. That's probably what you saw for MineCraft.
- There is also HTML/Phone Gap/Cordova that can be previewed on Node.js (either on the browser, or on a Node.js instance on the phone itself).
- And there is Android [App Inventor](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/), which gives you an awesome real-time preview, but which unfortunately was written in Scheme/LISP, so it can not easily be extended using other languages.

If you're just looking to speed up your save and compile cycle in Java, I'd recommend you switch to Android Studio (instead of Eclipse ADT), and only download updates from Android Studio's Stable Channel. Once properly set up, Android Studio will save you time (however, it still won't give you anything like a real-time preview, but I still highly recommend that IDE).

Comment: It's too bad there's no live code pushing... as of yet. I'll be sure to suggest it to them, it would be a nice feature, and it can be done. I love Android Studio, but unfortunately this project requires me to use ADT, or as I call it, Eclipse on Life Support for Android. Thank you for the reply!

Comment: Yes, it can be done, but I think it would require an entire reworking of the Android operating system. So I wouldn't hold my breath for it. In any case, here is the place where you could try re-opening an issue for it. http://b.android.com But the last time a similar issue was opened, it was declined. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14060&can=1&q=wysiwyg&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars